# How to count unique values of a visual on per quarter basis

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power BI visual like the attached image. Customer Name and Quarter End Date are columns of a table. "Future Customer" is a measure and is based on several other measures. I want the unique count of new customers in Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4. In this example -

```
Quarter 1 has 4 new customers
Q2 has 3 new customers
Q3 has 1 new customer
Q4 has 1 new customer.
```

[image]

Comment: You need row wise flag like yes/no? or quarter wise count of new customer? You date order in the sample data is not in proper order as well. Is that expected? That case how you will define the existing and new customer? Date order is important here.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these following steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1** Create a **Custom Column" to your table as below-

```
new customer = 

VAR current_row_customer = your_table_name[customer name]
VAR current_row_quarter_end_date = your_table_name[quarter end date]

VAR find_customer_previous_quarter =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[customer name]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[customer name] = current_row_customer
            && your_table_name[quarter end date] < current_row_quarter_end_date
    )
)

RETURN IF(find_customer_previous_quarter > 0,0,1)
```

**Step-2** just add **quarter end data** and newly created custom column **new customer** to your table visual. SUM aggregation will be automatically applied on new custom column and the final output will be as below-

[image]